# How to convert array data format

Tags: javascript, arraylist

I have the following array in number format. `Arr[12，713，6…]`, I am trying to convert them to `[0012,0713,0006…]`. I tried `padstart(4,"0")` but not working, anybody can help?

Comment: You do realize, `0012` as number will always be `12`. If you want `0012`, you will have to convert it to string. Try `Arr.map((num) => ("0000" + num.toString()).slice(-4) )`

Comment: Those are some strange Unicode characters that you are using...

Comment: padStart does work if you convert your number to a string.

`Arr.map(number => number.toString().padStart(4, "0"))`

Comment: @Rajesh The commas that OP used are not standard... `Arr[12，713，6…]` They are using a full-width comma instead of a standard comma... https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff0c/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [12,713,6];
var newArray = [];

array.forEach(function(element) {
  newArray.push(element.toString().padStart(4,0));
});

console.log(newArray);

//Or with array.map (requires ECMAScript 5)
console.log(array.map(number => number.toString().padStart(4, "0")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map your array with numbers, before you use `padStart` just make sure that the element is a string.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 323, 32].map((el) => el.toString().padStart(4, '0'));
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pad a number by adding n-number of zeroes before the value and then clipping the string n-places from the beginning.

```js
const padLeft = (v, ch, n) => (ch.repeat(n) + v).substr(-n);

let input = [ 12, 713, 6 ];
let output = input.map(x => padLeft(x, '0', 4));

console.log(output);
```